# How to remove 5th and 95th percentile values in ddply while calculating mean for each group

Tags: r, dplyr, outliers, quantile

I have a large dataset with several trait values for each species. I want to calculate the mean value of trait for each values excluding 5th percentile and 95th percentile. I am using ddply function but not able to do that. Any help is highly appreciated.

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: Base R's mean function: `mean(x, trim = 0.05, na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function `mean2` that computes the trimmed means.

```
mean2 <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE, probs = c(0.05, 0.95), ...){
  if(na.rm) x <- x[!is.na(x)]
  qq <- quantile(x, probs = probs)
  keep <- x > qq[1] & x < qq[2]
  mean(x[keep], ...)
}
```

Now `mutate` the data.frame with the function after grouping by `species`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(species) %>%
  mutate(mean = mean2(trait))
```

**Test data creation code**

```
set.seed(1234)
species <- sample(LETTERS[1:3], 20, TRUE)
trait <- sample(2:8, 20, TRUE)
trait[sample(20, 3)] <- sample(50:60, 3)
trait[sample(20, 1)] <- -2
df <- data.frame(species, trait)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However, I have NAs in my dataset and above code is giving me an error.

Comment: @GullCall the function with `na.rm = TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

With a `for` loop:

```
means = numeric()
for(i in df$Species){
  x = df$Trait[which(df$Species==i)]
  means[i] = mean(x[which(x<=quantile(x,0.95) & x>=quantile(x,0.05))])
  }
}
```

Dummy data used:

```
df = data.frame(
  Species = sample(rep(LETTERS[1:5],8), 40),
  Trait = rnorm(40, 5, 3))
```